# How does SolvStat Macro in Excel calculate partial derivatives?

Tags: excel, vba, derivative

I am working with the SolvStat Macro by E.J. Billo from the book "Excel for Chemists," and I'm unable to figure out how the partial derivatives are being calculated as anything but 0, as I don't see any explicit assignments which would change the value of either YCalc() array values or calc_ys range values. The following code is excerpted from the macro:

```
Dim YObsd(), YCalc(), ParmValu(), PartialDeriv(), Product(), ProdArray()

Set calc_ys = Application.InputBox("Podaj zakres wartości Y obliczonych z modelu." & msg1, _
            "SOLVER STATISTICS - Krok 2 z 4", , , , , , 8)

ReDim YObsd(N), YCalc(N)
x = 1
For Each F In calc_ys
   YCalc(x) = F.Value
   x = x + 1
Next

Set Parms = Application.InputBox("Zaznacz komórki zawierające  współczynniki obliczone metodą najmniejszych kwadratów przez Solvera." & msg2, _
"SOLVER STATISTICS – Krok  3 z 4", , , , , , 8)
N3 = Parms.Count
x = 1
For Each cell In Parms
   ParmValu(x) = cell.Value
   x = x + 1
Next
RMSD = Sqr(SSresiduals / (N - N3))

'Calculate table of partial differentials
increment = 0.000001
'1E-6 seems to be optimum value for increment for numerical differentiation.
'1E-3 is too large, 1E-12 is too small.  1E-9 gives results almost identical to 1E-6.
y = 1
For Each parm In Parms
   parm.Value = parm * (1 + increment)     'Increase regression coeffs by a small increment.
   If parm = 0 Then parm.Value = 1E-100    'If cell contains zero exactly, replace it with very small value
   CheckErrorSum = 0
   x = 1
   For Each cell In calc_ys
      PartialDeriv(x, y) = (cell - YCalc(x)) / (parm * increment)      'Partial deriv = delta(function)/delta(parameter)
      CheckErrorSum = CheckErrorSum + PartialDeriv(x, y)   'This sum used only for error checking.
      x = x + 1
   Next cell
   parm.Value = ParmValu(y)    'Restore original parameter value
   If CheckErrorSum = 0 Then
      MsgBox "Błąd w obliczeniach macierzy." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & 
      "Najpowszechniejsze błędy: " & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & _
         "1.  Niepoprawny wybór komórek Y(obl)." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & _
         "2.  Niepoprawny wybór komórek zawierających współczynniki regresji 
         " & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Zatrzymanie programu.", 16, "UNKNOWN ERROR"
      Exit Sub
   End If
   y = y + 1
Next parm
```

The YCalc(x) value contains the value that was assigned from the Range in Excel; however, cell (element in calc_ys) is a *slightly* different value, but from the code, it doesn't look like there should be any difference. In order to calculate the partial derivatives, there should be a difference, but I can't understand how/why this code produces different values for those two variables.

Here is a link to the full code: http://ue.poznan.pl/data/upload/articles/20140213/330de4761384630218/solvstat.doc

Answer (score 0):

Since calc_ys is a Range of cell(s), it doesn't contain the displayed values in the spreadsheet, but rather the formulas which calculate the displayed values. These formulas reference the parameters, which are modified in the partial derivatives section; therefore, the calc_ys cells in the Range are modified, too.